# Amp pages disappear in Google searches

Tags: amp-html

I use amp pages on my website and it passes the amp tests with flying colors. Even when mobile users click on the results, they go to the amp version. But sometimes it does not go to the amp version, it tries to open the main site directly. Then, when I bring Google bot without doing anything technical, after a few hours, it redirects to the amp version again. But in this time interval, I experience user loss and ranking loss.

When I check from the developer console in Google searches for the amp version;
-data-amp-cur
-data-amp-title
-data-amp-vgi

and labels like that. When it does not go to the amp version I mentioned, these tags disappear from the console in the search results. When I call a bot, it comes back after a few hours.

Although there is no problem with the amp tests, what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Ty adding link tag between your amp and non-amp sites, meta schema to your website.